# Select Union ALL...which one and how

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, union

I am new to SQL and its already driving me crazy!

I have a large MDB and I am trying to export some data from it as the tool I have from Access is not working.

Essentially I have an MDB file with multiple table.

The main Booking Table has columns such as ID, CustomerID
The Customer Table has columns such as FirstName and LastName but also the same ID numbers from the Booking Table Above.

I want to run a query on the Customer Table to give me back the FirstName and LastName for only the Rows that have the same IDs in the booking table.

Would any one be able to give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

This will do that:

```
Select FirstName,LastName 
from Customer c 
where exists(select 1 from Booking b where c.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh,  I have played with that concept on another MDB and come to the command:                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                              
select counter,payments
from tblbookingdetail
where exists (select 1 from tblbookingpayments where tblbookingdetail.counter = tblbookingpayments.bookingcode)